# Post child table data with parent doc data in rest api using retrofit in Android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit2

How to make the Model class with Retrofit Posting similar to the Postman request?

In postman the post request is working:

```
{
        "address_line1": "Address Creation Test",
        "city": "Mumbai",
        "country": "India",
        "address_type": "Billing",
        "gst_state": "Maharashtra",
        "gst_state_number": "27",
        "is_primary_address": 0,
        "is_shipping_address": 0,
        "disabled": 0,
        "is_your_company_address": 0,
        "doctype": "Address",
        "links": [
            {
                "link_doctype": "Lead",
                "link_name": "CRM-LEAD-2023-00022"
            }
        ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create model class from JSON then following links are helpful.

1. JSON to JAVA model - [jsonToPOJO](https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)
2. JSON to Kotlin data class  - [jsonToDataClass](https://json2kt.com/)

Comment: I have already created the model class which is similar to the one you have given. Now I need how to post via restrofit call (which I have already did but not working) . Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Ryan1 follow this link https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/retrofit-android-example-tutorial

Comment: The example in the documentation is wrongly given @Umesh P

Comment: I solved it at last.....The mistake I was doing is passing the data to post from retrofit without as list data so the data was not getting through the Model class.